# How can I set all RecyclerView items backgrounds to grey onSwiped?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**UPDATE** When I  `Log.i("adapterPos", String.valueOf(adapter.adapterPos));` in onSwiped, it returns -1 even before setting it to -1...

I have a `recyclerView`, as well as a `custom adapter` to display information about an exercise.

[image: app]

When a user taps on a recyclerView item, the items background is set to green, and the save button turns into an update button, so that the user can update their existing recorded exercises.

I also have an onSwiped method which is implemented inside my fragment. When a user swipes an item, it is deleted from the database.

When a user swipes to delete an item, I would like to set the background for ALL items back to the default (grey).

How could this be done?

**Note:** if item 2 is selected and the user decides to swipe item 1, even after item 1 is deleted, item 2 is still currently selected.

**Record Exercise Fragment** (Relevant code)

```
@Override
    public void onExerciseClicked(int position) {
        if (recyclerItemClicked == false) {
            saveBtn.setText("Update");
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerItemClicked = true;
            double selectedWeight = adapter.getWeight(position);
            String selectedWeightString = Double.toString(selectedWeight);
            editTextWeight.setText(selectedWeightString);

            int selectedReps = adapter.getReps(position);
            String selectedRepsString = Integer.toString(selectedReps);
            editTextReps.setText(selectedRepsString);

        } else {
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saveBtn.setText("Save");
            recyclerItemClicked = false;
        }
    }

    public void initRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new CompletedExercisesListAdapter2(allExercises, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void setExercises(List<Log_Entries> exercises) {
        allExercises.clear();
        allExercises.addAll(exercises);
    }

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            int logID = allExercises.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLog_id();
            logViewModel.deleteByID(logID);
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saveBtn.setText("Save");

 Log.i("adapterPos", String.valueOf(adapter.adapterPos));  // this is always -1 for some reason

            // backup the currently selected position
            int selectedPos = adapter.adapterPos;
            // change the currently selected position to -1
            adapter.adapterPos = -1;
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);

        }
    };
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CompletedExercisesListAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener;
    private List<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    public int adapterPos = -1;
    public boolean isSelected = false;

    public CompletedExercisesListAdapter2(ArrayList<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
        this.allCompletedExercises = allCompletedExercises;
        this.onExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;

        if (viewType == 0) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderOne(view, onExerciseClickListener);
        }

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderTwo(view, onExerciseClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            ViewHolderOne viewHolderOne = (ViewHolderOne) holder;

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            }
            else {
                    viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }

            viewHolderOne.textViewExerciseName.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderOne.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderOne.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));

        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            ViewHolderTwo viewHolderTwo = (ViewHolderTwo) holder;

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }

            viewHolderTwo.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderTwo.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allCompletedExercises.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        // if list is sorted chronologically
        if (position == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName().equals(allCompletedExercises.get(position - 1).getChildExerciseName())) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewExerciseName;
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;

        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderOne(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewExerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ExerciseName3);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number56);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight78);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss0);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_relative);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            if (isSelected) {
                adapterPos = -1;
                isSelected = false;

            } else {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                isSelected = true;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;
        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderTwo(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_rel);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());

            if (!isSelected) {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                isSelected = true;

            } else {
                adapterPos = -1;
                isSelected = false;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public interface OnExerciseClickListener {
        void onExerciseClicked(int position);
    }

    public double getWeight(int position) {
        double weight = allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted();
        return weight;
    }

    public int getReps(int position) {
        int reps = allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps();
        return reps;
    }
}
```

Comment: When the user swipes the item, you want to delete the item and remove the background color in the selected row ?

Comment: When the user swipes to delete the item, what would be the background colour of all the other items ? I guess they would all be gray except the one that was selected which would be green. So, regardless of which item is swiped, you want to change the color of that selected item to gray instead of green on swipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onSwipe()`, just reset the `adapterPos` of your `adapter` object to -1 and call `notifyItemChanged()` on that position.

```
                // backup the currently selected position
                int selectedPos = adapter.adapterPos;
                // change the currently selected position to -1
                adapter.adapterPos = -1;
                adapter.isSelected = false;
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
```

---

Note: `onSwipe()` is called after the `ViewHolder` being swiped fully.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the suggestion, I have tried to implement it however the background of the item is not changing `onSwiped` . I believe it is because the colour is currently being set in bindviewholder of my adapter.

Comment: Lets say item 2 has just been clicked on, its background turns green. If I was then to delete (swipe)  any item (1/2/3 ect) the background remains the same grey as a result of this method in my 2 viewHolders: `if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            } `

Comment: once, try my edited answer. I think just resetting the position of selected viewholder on `onSwipe` will do its job.

Comment: Also get rid of the if else logic which checks `swipeDetected` to set the colour of the viewholder to black_grey when it is true.

Comment: when I remove  `else {                 viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);             }` the background always remains green, even onclick.

Comment: Not that one, I meant `if` with `swipeDetected` variable involved.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion, however even after it runs, adapterPos for the selected item still remains the same. This:  `adapter.adapterPos = -1;` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please once edit the question to reflect your current code. I hope the else part which you removed earlier is still there and the part involving `swipeDetected` variable is removed.

Comment: Inside `onSwipe`, once log to see the value of `adapter.adapterPos`.

Comment: the result is -1 each time, before and after setting it.

Comment: Once, try moving the `itemTouchHelperCallback` definition to inside of `initRecyclerView()` method. It looks like the `adapter` is not initialized even.

Comment: Previously, it was a class variable. That's why it was created in the **constructor** call for that `RecordExerciseFragment` class. Inside it, we used `adapter` object which is later initialized in `onViewCreated()` or `onCreateView()`[I assumed]. So, that's where the things went wrong I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you need to do for this to work is to make sure that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is executed once after you set `adapterpos= -1`.
`notifyDataSetChanged()` will reexecute onBindViewHolder for the **entire** adapter as opposed to `notifyItemChanged()` which should result in all items evaluating to a gray background.

you are actually already doing this in your viewholders onClick method in order to prevent multiple items to have a green background at once. so yust execute the method again after a swipe. so just do the following:

```
        @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        int logID = allExercises.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLog_id();
        logViewModel.deleteByID(logID);
        clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        saveBtn.setText("Save");//<-- why if no item is selected?

        // backup the currently selected position
        //int selectedPos = adapter.adapterPos;<-- why would you do this, nothing is not shown as selected
        // change the currently selected position to -1
        adapter.adapterPos = -1;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//now everything will be gray

    }
```

this will work for sure but it will mess with the delete animation you might be using after the swipe. following the previous answer another code that might work is the following:

```
        @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int copyOfAdapterPos=adapterPos;
        adapterPos=-1;
        notifyItemChanged(copyOfAdapterPos);
        
        int logID = allExercises.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getLog_id();
        logViewModel.deleteByID(logID);
        clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        saveBtn.setText("Save");//<-- why if no item is selected?

        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());//now everything will be gray

    }
```

i havnt tested it but if it works it will look nicer

Comment: Thankyou very much for the suggestion, however this does not change anything. I believe the problem is something to do with `adapter.adapterPos` always being -1

Comment: if the click action is working correctly then adapterPos must be working. have you tried logging the value of adapterPos?actually if you are shure that adapterPos is-1 at the time when notify datasetchanged is executed i dont see how anything could remain green

Comment: did you try both suggestions?

Comment: `adapter.adapterpos` is always -1 (I do not know why this is).

Comment: I am also confused as to why the background remains green.

Comment: i think the problem might lie with your isSelected boolean variable,  in your place i would log every variable involved in setting adapterPos. there is a small chance that before swiping the action of putting your finger on an item is evaluated as a click. what would help is for you to tell us exactly how the code is not working. i assume that after swiping some itemremains selected, which item is this? the same that was selected before? maybe the code is failing at some point i recomend that you try to execute notifydatasetchanged() on button press instead of on swipe just to see that it work